Is there a means to prevent a method from being called in an async or non-single-thread context at compile time?
I have found it is very useful at times - primarily to avoid excessive indenting, but occasionally for other purposes - to be able to use Monitor.Enter and Monitor.Exit instead of the lock keyword, embedded in an implementation of IDisposable.
However, this opens up an easy bug which, as far as I can tell, C# cannot catch at compile time without help - namely, that if you use this technique inappropriately in an async method which may run different chunks of the code on different threads, there is no guarantee that Monitor.Exit will be called on the same thread as Monitor.Enter.
Since it's my own code, I've thus far side stepped the issue with the time-honoured technique of "That stupid thing you could do? Don't do it", but I'd like some better guide rails if they're available. What I have in mind is something like an attribute that I could put on a method that basically says "Do not allow this method to be called when in an async block of code".
Does such a thing exist?
Please note, I'm not looking to be pointed at Semaphores - the issue isn't so much the choice of solution as whether I can add guiderails so that a program will not compile, or the LockHelper constructor or method would fail when this situation might arise due to oversight somewhere.
Example of the issue:
LockHelper class
public struct LockHelper : IDisposable
{
    private readonly object _target;
    private bool _locked;
    private bool _disposed;
    public LockHelper(object target, bool startLocked = true)
    {
        _target = target;
        _locked = false;
        _disposed = false;

        if (startLocked)
            Lock();
    }

    private void Lock()
    {
        AssertNotDisposed();
        if (_locked)
            return;
        _locked = true;
        Monitor.Enter(_target);
    }

    private void AssertNotDisposed()
    {
        if (!_disposed) 
            return;
        throw new ObjectDisposedException(nameof(LockHelper));
    }

    private void Unlock() 
    {
        AssertNotDisposed();
        if (!_locked)
            return;
        _locked = false;
        Monitor.Exit(_target);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_disposed)
            return;
        Unlock();
        _disposed = true;
    }
}

Incorrect usage
readonly object _sync = new object();
readonly IAsyncService _service;

async Task DoSomething() 
{
   // Start on thread #123
   using var lh = new LockHelper(_sync);
   
   await _service.SomeAsyncCall();

   // Resume on some other threadpool thread, call it #456
   // That means the _sync is still locked by #123, but we have NO WAY to unlock it 
   // Therefore disposal of #123 will happen on that other thread, and myriad other issues
}



I think such a lockHelper will increase the risk of deadlocks no matter what you do. Locks tend to work best when protecting small sections of code. Your LockHelper makes it easier to hold a lock between method calls. And the risk of deadlocks increases the more code you run while holding the lock. If the nesting level is a problem I would consider other ways to refactor the code, or other synchronization methods.

side note: mutable structs (see: _disposed and _locked etc) are usually a very bad idea; it is absurdly easy to end up making copied and violating the rule you're trying to enforce; for example, placing a LockHelper into a readonly field would be sufficient to make Unlock and Lock work incorrectly (by making defensive copies); a trick I've seen (and used) a few times to help with this is to declare the type as a readonly struct, and lie, by using Unsafe.AsRef to make a readonly field mutable (so you can change the value in-place without a defensive copy ever being created)

In general I'm not a fan of mutable structs either, and honestly if this is being passed around outside of literally using var x = new LockHelper(_sync); then it's being used dangerously. Mainly I use this for syntactic sugar in place of the lock equivalent of a using expression, though it's seen some use as a way to defer control over locking/unlocking to the OWNER of some _sync object rather than exposing the object that needs to be locked.

Having said that, it's very interesting to know that readonly structs can lie about their readonlyness. Not in that it's something I want to make use of imminently, but definitely something I'll watch out for in weird edge scenarios.

IMHO just use SemaphoreSlim instead, as that works with async code.

SemaphoreSlim doesn't work for this actually - the reason being that it has an internal count of calls beyond which it won't allow anything past. So if you start off all methods by locking the semaphore, then you can never call your own methods. For some scenarios, you can work around that by having an internal and an external version for each method - but the moment an event may effect a change on the class you're working with, you'll get the same deadlock all over again.

To the best of my knowledge there is nothing specific in the compiler that are intended to detect this. You could potentially write your own analyzer, however: I suspect that you could abuse ref struct here; a ref struct cannot be put into an async state machine, because it cannot be off the stack. If you make public ref struct LockHelper (noting that you can't explicitly implement IDisposable on a ref struct, but using still works via the public void Dispose()): that might be sufficient for your needs.

I hadn't realised you could get disposal on ref structs... I can probably work with that, since the restrictions are basically the same kind of thing I'm after for the most part. Thanks :)

Having put this in, looks like it does the job (albeit with some very slight new restrictions that are probably on the sensible side)

@tobriand I tried to use langver to see where the dispose thing works/fails, but it looks like Roslyn doesn't do a true reflection of language versions for this case - it compiles just fine for C# 2 (it we fix the var and $"..." etc usage); I can't be bothered to check the hard way with different compilers ;p

Thanks for this Marc - that's super helpful to know. Thankfully I'm generally working with  Roslyn compilers, so the take-home message is that this should always work as long as ref structs compile for my use-cases.
